# How do I restart a certain app pool on IIS remotely via a command line?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis

I am an admin on the box and would like to stop/start a certain app pool without having to log into the box.

Is there a command line to do this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following command does it, if you're on the machine. Now, this is not a remote command. But if you have CIFS open to the webserver, you can do it with PSEXEC. If you can't/don't want to RDP or PSEXEC to the server, you could also call it via telnet or SSH if you have those protocols enabled/installed.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>iisapp.vbs /?
Description: list IIS application pools and associated worker processes.
             Recycle application pools.

Syntax: IIsApp.vbs [{ /a <app_pool_id> | /p <pid> } [/r] ]

Parameters:

Value              Description
/a <app_pool_id>   Specify an application pool by name. Surround
                   <app_pool_id> with quotes if it contains spaces.
                   If used alone without an accompanying action,
                   IIsApp.vbs will report PIDs of currently running
                   w3wp.exe processes serving pool <app_pool_id>.
/p <pid>           Specify a process by process ID. If used alone
                   without an accompanying action, IIsApp.vbs will
                   report the AppPoolId of the w3wp process specified
                   by <pid>. When a PID is specified with /r, that PID
                   is mapped to an application pool and the action is
                   taken upon the application pool. If a PID is given
                   for a web garden, i.e. an application pool served
                   by more than one w3wp, then all w3wp's for that
                   application pool will be acted upon.
/r                 Recycles the application pool.

DEFAULT: no switches will print out the PID and AppPoolId.
```

Comment: Good stuff here! +1